# Como concatenar duas listas encadeadas?

Tags: c++

Criei este código inicializando uma lista, porém preciso aprimorar ele, criando uma função que concatene duas e no final imprima o valor das duas concatenadas... Isso, Eu não sei fazer.

**Protótipo Sugerido:** `no *concatena(no * inicio1, no * inicio2);`

**Parâmetros:** Ponteiro para o início da 1ª. lista (que pode ser NULL) e ponteiro para o início da 2ª. lista (que pode ser NULL).

**Retorno:** Ponteiro para o início da lista resultante da concatenação

```
 //Lista encadeada Simples
//Imprimindo a lista

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct No {
    //Variavel Valor
    int valor;
    //Ponteiro para o próximo Nó
    No * ptr;
};
No * inserirInicio(No * lista, int num);

void imprimir(No * lista);
main(){
    //Declara e inicializa a LIsta
    //O Ponteiro chamado de LISTA e é NULO/Vazio
    No * lista = NULL;
    //Recebera as alterações feitas com a função abaixo

    lista = inserirInicio(lista, 10);
    lista = inserirInicio(lista, 20);
    lista = inserirInicio(lista, 30);
    lista = inserirInicio(lista, 40);
    lista = inserirInicio(lista, 50);
    imprimir(lista);


}

No * inserirInicio(No * lista, int num)
{
        //Variavel temporária
        No * tmp;
        //Se esta vazia Eu crio o elemento e aponto a lista para Ele
        //Aponta para o nov nó
        tmp = new No;
        //Configurando o novo valor
        //Guardo na variavel NUM
        tmp -> valor = num;
        //Apontar para o primeiro cara
        tmp -> ptr = lista;
        lista = tmp;
        //Retorna o novo inicio da lista
        return lista;
    }

//Imprimindo os valores
void imprimir(No * lista)
{
    No * atual;
    atual = lista;//atual aponta para lista
    while(atual!= NULL)
    {
        cout << atual -> valor << endl;
        atual = atual -> ptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque você nao tenta fazer o seguinte cria uma função na que receba as duas lista.NO código você poderia fazer o seguinte usar essa sua função imprimir só que você terá que aumentar as variáveis e acho que se você deixar com um for sera melhor

Comment: @user3652472 Eu ja pensei em tudo isso, porém sou novato mesmo em programação, não consigo executar a parte pratica.

Comment: Na teoria, seu ponteiro nunca será nulo. Ele só vai apontar para *`p + sizeof(p)`* em uma iteração, o que é "válido". Você precisa saber onde é o final da lista para fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenação entre duas listas tem uma solução bem simples e bem interessante, que é uma propriedade do próprio tipo de lista:

Para fazê-la, deve-se levar em conta primeiramente essas propriedades: cada `No` guarda somente um ponteiro para o próximo item da lista, não para o anterior. Isso significa, portanto, que o último `No` de uma lista não aponta para `No` algum(e, no caso de seu programa, o último `No` em si é nulo).
Em segundo lugar, concatenar, por definição, é a união de dois conjuntos por suas extremidades. Nesse caso, o fim de `inicio1` e o início de `inicio2` na função `No *concatena(No * inicio1, No * inicio2);`.

Portanto, para realizar a concatenação, vc deve procurar o último `No` de `inicio1` e `inserí-lo ao início` de `inicio2`.

Por exemplo:

```
No *concatena(No * inicio1, No * inicio2){
    No* fim = NULL;
    No* iterador = inicio1;
    while(iterador->ptr != NULL){
        iterador = iterador->ptr;
    }
    iterador = inserirInicio(inicio2, iterador->valor);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Lista* concatList(Lista* a, Lista* b){

    Lista* temp = b;
    while(temp != NULL){
        a = inserirFim(a, temp->item);
        temp = temp->prox;
    }
    return a;
}
```